# Ubuntu 14.04 suddenly shuts down on my AWS EC2 t2.large instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, system-shutdown

We are running a campaign over the weekend and suddenly at some point the AWS EC2 t2.large instance broadcast a shutdown message.

We are trying to find it on all logs possible such as syslog, audit.log, access.log and it doesn't show any clue. And tried checking our application level logs but not also no clue.

Below was the message we have seen in our console.

```
Broadcast message from userhere@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX
        (unknown) at XX:XX

The system is going down for power off NOW!
```

We are expecting something to be as obvious as possible from all the logs but it turns out that it does not describe any suspicious activities.

Comment: Is the instance tied to an ASG? Was it the root user that sent the broadcast message?

Comment: Hi @RodrigoM, no it wasn't tied to any ASG. The instance is standalone server without any automation. We have received it using our root access.

Comment: Hi @RodrigoM, we have already figured out the cause of these issue. It was due to hardware and network degradation happened on AWS side that triggers their EC2 maintenance team to handle it as quick as possible.